# At what point to the curves $y=ax$, $y=a/x$, and $y=x^3/a$ Intersect with one another when a>0

Tags: calculus, integration

Hi this has been bugging me for a while now I have the answers however they only detail the points I have so far been  unable to figure out how to find these points. [Image of problem with arrows to unknown points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbpW6.jpg)

Comment: How do you find usually the intersection of two curves ? Isn't  $y=y $ ? and then proceed to find the value(s) of $x$ ?

Comment: I tried to make y=ax equal to y=a/x but I just end up with a/a = x/x and I'm not particularly sure how you extrapolate the co-ords (1,a) from this.

Comment: If you get $a/a=x/x$, you made a mistake.

Comment: Hi jpvee, Nizar cleared up the first one up in his other comment and I've fixed my rearranging now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeedd to find the intersection points  we may do the following:

$y=y \Rightarrow ax=\frac{a}{x} \Rightarrow x^2=1 \text{ as }  a>0 \Rightarrow x=1 \text{ or } x=-1 $. Thus in this case you have two points of intersection . The first for  $x=1$ then $y=a$ and the second $x=-1$ so $y=-a$ .Thus the points are $(1,a)$  and  $(-1,-a)$.

Similarly you may proceed for the other cases.

Comment: Awesome thank you Nizar that cleared it up i'll try the other two now :)

Comment: Okay so I have the rearranging sorted now x^4 = a^2 and x^2 = a^2. I'm not sure how I correctly substitute these into the y= equations. Also where can I find a formatting guide to tidy up exponents etc. Thank you :)

Comment: if you take $ y=y \Rightarrow  \frac{a}{x}=\frac{x^3}{a}  \Rightarrow x^4=a^2 \Rightarrow  (x^2+a)(x-\sqrt{a})(x+\sqrt{a})=0$, here we consider just real solutions, no complex ones. so you have in this case two intersecting points at  $x=\sqrt{a}$ and at  $x=-\sqrt{a}$ .

Comment: For having a good format you can check this  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference. Plus you can check this   http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Find three pairs intersection  points pairwise, let them  be

$$ ( x_{12},x_{23}, x_{31} )$$

each between

$$ ( x_1(y), x_2 (y)) ,...,... $$

Find $ \int (x_2-x_1) dy ,\int (x_3-x_2) dy $ and add them up.